# Use xpath to locate a complex element with attributes and children

Tags: xpath

Given this XML

```
<well bulkShift="0.000000" diameter="5.000000" hidden="false" name="67-1-TpX-10" filename="67-1-TpX-10.well">
    <metadata/>
    <unit>ftUS</unit>
    <colour blue="1.000000" green="1.000000" hue="" red="1.000000"/>
    <tvd clip="false"/>
    <associatedcheckshot>25-1-X-14</associatedcheckshot>
    <associatedwelllog>HDRA_67-1-TpX-10</associatedwelllog>
    <associatedwelllog>NPHI_67-1-TpX-10</associatedwelllog>
</well>
```

I can select the element with this XPath

```
//well[@bulkShift=0 and @diameter=5 and @hidden='false' and @name='67-1-TpX-10' and @filename='67-1-TpX-10.well']
```

However I need to be much more specific in that I need  to find the element with these specific child nodes given that the child elements (metadata,unit,colour, etc) can appear in any order inside the element.

Ideally I'd like to be able to select this node with only a single XPath query.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This template match also childs and attributed on childs

```
<xsl:template match="well[@hidden='false'][./unit='ftUS' or ./tvd/@clip='false']">
    well found!
</xsl:template>
```

or in one go:

```
<xsl:template match="well[@hidden='false' and (./unit='ftUS' or ./tvd/@clip='false')]">
    well found!
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I am learning `XPATH` currently. So I have a question to you. why `[@hidden='false'][./unit='ftUS' or ./tvd/@clip='false'` can't be written inside one `[..]` ? May be a stupid question,still I need to know to reduce my gap of understanding.

Comment: okay. so the two `[]` are for `and` operations? If I want to write it in a single `[]` how should I write?

Comment: Thanks friend.. I was expecting something like that,although that was my guess. You made my guess true.. :)

Comment: It is more fun if you ask a question here on SO after your tried something and got stuck. You'll learn a lot that way. I'm not an xslt expert but I'll answer xslt questions where I can so we'll meet on SO again. This also gives other members a chance to help out as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the test for children like the test for attributes to your predicate 
e.g.:

```
//well[@bulkShift=0 and @diameter=5 and @hidden='false' and @name='67-1-TpX-10' and @filename='67-1-TpX-10.well']
     [metadata and unit and colour]
```

Having a list off predicates `[ predicate1 ][ predicate2 ]` is the same as have one with and operation.

Comment: That's not entirely true. Multiple predicates change the value of `position()`. If you're not using `position()`, then they're equivalent.